# Getting different response for each aws lambda api

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, api, lambda

I am using Lambda function with Node.js 10x in aws.

I am getting different response for each function when I call API for post values from postman.
e.g. {"user": "229"} it gives me event.user or event.body.user. Please explain.

Below is code for my template for API Gateway.

```
{
  "body" : $input.json('$'),
  "headers": {
    #foreach($header in $input.params().header.keySet())
    "$header": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($header))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  },
  "method": "$context.httpMethod",
  "params": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().path.keySet())
    "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().path.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  },
  "query": {
    #foreach($queryParam in $input.params().querystring.keySet())
    "$queryParam": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().querystring.get($queryParam))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  }  
}
```

Comment: Are you saying the event received in Lambda is different?

Comment: Yes correct, for some function it's giving "event.user" or  "event.body.user", Please explain.

Comment: Is it possible you are sending your requests with different content-type headers? i.e. bypassing your mapping in some instances

Comment: We are sending same content type "application/json" for all API Gateway using Lambda function. Please suggest.